# Why aren't icon shown in xfce4-panel menu items when loaded into Unity?

Tags: unity, xfce-panel

In my Xubuntu session, icons appear correctly in my xfce4-panel menu applet.
If I launch xfce4-panel in my Unity session, the icons are missing.

Comment: Is your Xfce panel set to the top?

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: screenshots probably will help (crop to the area showing the applet icons in XFCE and then what you see in unity)

Comment: I believe you don't need screenshots. Consider I receive an error about the notification area selection: "The notification area lost selection. Most likely another widget took over the function of a notification area. This area will be unused."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably those icons are related to something in notification area.
In Unity notification area is already handled by another indicator, and the one in xfce4-panel (or whatever else) would conflict. That's why the second loaded notification area will always fizzle.

Answer (score -2):

Xfce4 is gtk2, unity is gtk3/qt/javascript. The enviroments are different